# Prolong iOS app suspend time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, suspend

When I press the home button my app is suspended correctly, however it only lasts a few minutes. If I leave it for a short while and return to it the app starts up fresh.

I'm not running any background tasks in my app and other apps stay suspended for much, much longer than mine.

What could be the potential causes of this? Is it likely I have operations running in the background that I'm not aware of and iOS is killing my app when it is short on memory?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to hold?

Comment: I have two webViews and some image states I'd like it to hold. It isn't necessary to hold them indefinitely, so I haven't used NSUserdefaults.. It's more that I don't want the user to have to wait the 2-3 seconds every time they switch back to my app.

Comment: Yes, maybe you're loading a lot o data in webview and the app is getting terminated earlier than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apps that are using the most memory are terminated first in the background.  So the likely cause is that your app is consuming more memory than you think it is.  I'd start with ensuring that your memory is being managed correctly.

[Apple - App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)